# Standardized way to find an element in a container?

Tags: c++, std

Is there a standardized way for searching a value (key for (unordered_)map) in a container ?

By example for this function :

```
template <class T, class V> bool find(T const &t, V const &v) {
    // For std::vector : return std::find(t.begin(), t.end(), v) != t.end();
    // For std::(unordered_)set and (unordered_)map : return t.find(v) != t.end();
    return ?
}
```

I use :

```
template <class T, class V> bool find(T const &t, V const &v) {
    return std::find(t.begin(), t.end(), v) != t.end();
}

template <class V> bool find(std::set<V> const &t, V const &v) {
    return t.find(v) != t.end();
}

template <class V> bool find(std::unordered_set<V> const &t, V const &v) {
    return t.find(v) != t.end();
}

template <class K, class V> bool find(std::map<K, V> const &t, K const &v) {
    return t.find(v) != t.end();
}

template <class K, class V> bool find(std::unordered_map<K, V> const &t, K const &v) {
    return t.find(v) != t.end();
}
```

But does std have this kind of stuff ?

Comment: [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)

Comment: @DarthRubik: Read the question body, not just the title.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The same could go for you. All they did was repeat the question title in the body.

Comment: @user6412786: I think something's wrong with your browser. There's 2 code blocks in there that show the intent. Perhaps you're not seeing them. Anyway, they clearly demonstrate that `std::find` is not an answer to this question.

Comment: Since you just want a boolean telling if the container `t` contains a value `v`, you can use `boost::algorithm::any_of_equal(t,v)` (for the generic case, not std::map), which returns a bool. Or `std::any_of(t.begin(), t.end(), [v](auto a){ return a==v; })`, if you don't like boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing standard to do this for you - but we can easily write such a solution. The "special" part is whether or not the container has a `find()` member function. If it does, we should use it. If it doesn't, we fall back to using `std::find()`. Regardless, we want to compare the result to `end()`.

So we write a *preferred* overload for `.find()` and a *fallback* overload for the other one:

```
template <class C, class V>
auto generic_find_impl(C const& container, V const& value, int /* unused */)
    -> decltype(container.find(value))
{
    return container.find(value);
}

template <class C, class V>
auto generic_find_impl(C const& container, V const& value, ...)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return std::find(begin(container), end(container), value);
}

template <class C, class V>
bool generic_find(C const& container, V const& value) {
    using std::end;
    return generic_find_impl(container, value, 0) != end(container);
}
```

If `container.find(value)` is a valid expression, the first overload will be preferred due to the last argument (`int` is a better match for `0` than `...`). If it's not a valid expression, then the first overload is not viable and we only get the second overload.

Comment: Thank you, that'S FIN(A)E for me ;)

Answer (score -1):

So you're basically asking is there a function that will call `t.find` for you? No. The library fundamentals TS v2 is proposing a series of non-member `erase` and `erase_if` overloads that are implemented like this:

```
  template<typename _Key, typename _Compare, typename _Alloc,
       typename _Predicate>
    inline void
    erase_if(set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>& __cont, _Predicate __pred)
    { __detail::__erase_nodes_if(__cont, __pred); }

  template<typename _Key, typename _Compare, typename _Alloc,
       typename _Predicate>
    inline void
    erase_if(multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>& __cont, _Predicate __pred)
    { __detail::__erase_nodes_if(__cont, __pred); }
```

On the other hand, here are the overloads for `list`:

```
  template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc, typename _Predicate>
    inline void
    erase_if(list<_Tp, _Alloc>& __cont, _Predicate __pred)
    { __cont.remove_if(__pred); }

  template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc, typename _Up>
    inline void
    erase(list<_Tp, _Alloc>& __cont, const _Up& __value)
    {
      using __elem_type = typename list<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type;
      erase_if(__cont, [&](__elem_type& __elem) { return __elem == __value; });
    }
```

As you can see, there's no way to have a uniform erase. The logic similarly extends to `find`. Your approach is fine, but I would follow the style of the standard and add the template parameters for the comparator, allocator, etc. as well just to be robust.

Answer (score -1):

You can provide a unary predicate to the find_if function

```
template <class K, class V> bool find(std::unordered_map<K, V> const &t, K  const &v) {
    return std::find_if(t.begin(), t.end(), [v](const std::pair<K, V>& x) {return x.first == v; }) != t.end();
}

int main()
{  
    std::unordered_map<int,char> example = {{1,'a'},{2,'b'}};
    std::cout << find(example, 2);  // true
    std::cout << find(example, 3);  // false
}
```